# Can functions with the onlyOwner modifier be called by the owner if they are set with visibility external instead of public?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, visibility, binance-smart-chain

I have some functions that I'm trying to save gas on.
`onlyOwner` modifier is self explanatory.

This is related to a previous question that I had, where I noticed that `address(this)` is different from `msg.sender` in a given contract. Upon further reading I get the impression that `address(this)` is a hash of `msg.sender`, but the two are not considered the same. Is this correct?

Since `address(this)` is related to the owner address, is the owner address (`msg.sender`, set within the contract's constructor) considered different enough from the contract address `address(this)` so as to be considered `external` visibility?

```
// can the owner (set in the constructor) call this function once it is deployed on the blockchain?
function setXYZ(address _address) external onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
 XYZ[_address] = 4;
 return true;
}
```

Seems to work when I test it within my IDE, but I don't know if there is a difference in implementations between my test environment and the blockchain environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Upon further reading I get the impression that `address(this)` is a hash of `msg.sender`, but the two are not considered the same. Is this correct?*

`address(this)` returns address of the currently executed contract. When a contract is deployed, it's assigned an address which is determined by hash of "the deployer address combined with other data". Once the contract address is assigned, it never changes.

On the other hand, `msg.sender` reflects address of whoever is currently executing the contract. So if Alice executes a function, `msg.sender` is her address - and if Bob executes the same function, `msg.sender` reflects his address.

---

As the OpenZeppelin `Ownable` code [shows](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.8.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L28), the deployer address (`msg.sender` in `constructor`) becomes the initial `owner`.

And the `onlyOwner` modifier validates whether the current `msg.sender` is the owner. If they match - all good. If the currrent `msg.sender` is different from the `owner`, it reverts the transaction.

---

> *Seems to work when I test it within my IDE, but I don't know if there is a difference in implementations between my test environment and the blockchain environment.*

This code will work the same on all EVM networks.

There are few very small differences between the EVM implementation in emulators and live networks (as well as between different live networks). But they mostly affect low-level features such as ordering of transactions in a block or gas usage optimizations.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. So assuming I am the owner, I can mark onlyOwner functions as `external` instead of `public` to save gas, and not be locked out of calling them once they are deployed on the blockchain? (I know my contract will never internally call any function that I mark as `external`).

Comment: @Ashraile That's correct